# openxlsx dates don't match Excel dates

Tags: r, excel, datetime, openxlsx

I see like questions on stackoverflow but haven't had any luck with their solutions.

I'm reading in dates into R. An example of my dates are:

```
2018-01-01  1:00:00 AM
2018-01-01  2:00:00 AM
2018-01-01  3:00:00 AM
2018-01-01  4:00:00 AM
```

This are in PST timezone but I live in a different timezone.

R reads the following number values:

```
43101.04
43101.08
43101.12
43101.17

openxlsx::convertToDateTime(43101.04)
```

Returns: "2018-01-01 00:57:36 EST"

```
openxlsx::convertToDateTime(43101.08)
```

Returns:  "2018-01-01 01:55:12 EST"

```
openxlsx::convertToDateTime(43101.12)
```

Returns:  "2018-01-01 02:52:48 EST"

```
openxlsx::convertToDateTime(43101.17)
```

Returns:  "2018-01-01 04:04:48 EST"

How would I fix this code?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is working correctly, it's just that the datetimes (in the number format) have been rounded to two decimal places, so there's a bit of inaccuracy when we then convert them into datetimes.

[image: spreadsheet showing why the numbers are inaccurate]

In order to fix it, you want to get a version of the Excel file with more decimal places in the datetime column(s). Barring that, you could potentially round your dates to the nearest hour.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Extending the answer from @Mark with code.

```r
require(openxlsx)
#> Loading required package: openxlsx
require(openxlsx2)
#> Loading required package: openxlsx2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'openxlsx2'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:openxlsx':
#> 
#>     col2int, int2col, temp_xlsx

dates <- as.POSIXct(
  c(
    "2018-01-01 1:00:00 AM",
    "2018-01-01 2:00:00 AM",
    "2018-01-01 3:00:00 AM",
    "2018-01-01 4:00:00 AM"
  ),
  tz = "America/Los_Angeles"
)

tmp <- openxlsx2::temp_xlsx()
openxlsx::write.xlsx(dates, tmp, overwrite = TRUE)

# openxlsx with conversion
dd <- openxlsx::read.xlsx(tmp, detectDates = TRUE)$x

# differences in print
print(dd)
#> [1] 43101.04 43101.08 43101.12 43101.17
sprintf("%f", dd)
#> [1] "43101.041667" "43101.083333" "43101.125000" "43101.166667"

# convertToDateTime uses all decimal places
openxlsx::convertToDateTime(dd)
#> [1] "2018-01-01 01:00:00 CET" "2018-01-01 02:00:00 CET"
#> [3] "2018-01-01 03:00:00 CET" "2018-01-01 04:00:00 CET"

# openxlsx2 (does not require the conversion)
openxlsx2::read_xlsx(tmp, colNames = TRUE, detectDates = TRUE)$x
#> [1] "2018-01-01 01:00:00 CET" "2018-01-01 02:00:00 CET"
#> [3] "2018-01-01 03:00:00 CET" "2018-01-01 04:00:00 CET"
```